# typegraphql delegate query fields to field resolver

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I want a user query which delegates it's fields to the field resolvers below. What do I return from the query to allow this behaviour?

```
@ObjectType()
class User {
  @Field((_type) => ID)
  id!: string;

  @Field((_type) => [View])
  saved!: View[];
}


@Resolver(of => User)
export class UserResolver {
  @Authorized()
  @Query((_returns) => User, { nullable: false })
  async user(@Ctx() { prisma, uid }: context.AuthorizedContext) {
    return {
      id: uid,
    };
  }

  @FieldResolver()
  async saved(
    @Root() { id }: User,
    @Ctx() { prisma }: context.AuthorizedContext
  ) {
    console.log("HELLO")

    const savedViews = await prisma.saved.findMany({
      where: { userId: id },
      include: { View: true },
    });

    return savedViews.map((dboView) => dboView.View);
  }
}
```

I've tried not returning the fields in the query, but get a `Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.saved`

Comment: This is automatic :) Simply remove `saved` from `async user ...` and try to `query user { id, saved }`. The `id` is resolved by the `user` call and `saved` by the field resolver. Simple as it is :)

Comment: @CarloCorradini Still no luck :( I've updated the question with what I'm trying at the moment. I am targeting es2018 for ts compilation so it's not that either. Been stuck on this for hours

Comment: @CarloCorradini that console.log is never fired

Comment: Try: `@FieldResolver((_type) => [View])`

Comment: @CarloCorradini still no difference. Tearing my hair out, considering ripping typegraphql out and just using codegen at this point

Comment: No! You will regret this choice ahah

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: If you want a working example, here is my project: https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster

Comment: @CarloCorradini I was loving it until this issue haha

Comment: Field definition: https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/blob/main/server/src/graphql/entities/Cpu.ts#L88

Comment: Field resolver: https://github.com/carlocorradini/reCluster/blob/main/server/src/graphql/resolvers/cpu/CpuResolver.ts#L62

Comment: @CarloCorradini code: https://github.com/sh-k-l/viewsapp/blob/main/src/schema/user.ts

Comment: Can you share a minimal example without Next boilerplate and env keys? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the field declaration from your class? The field resolver is sufficient to add the field to your schema.

```
@ObjectType()
class User {
  @Field((_type) => ID)
  id: string;
}
```

in your resolver:

```
@FieldResolver() // this is sufficient!
  async saved( ... )
```